# Best way to get a decent result from this Array check?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to get a decent result that I can do something with, but feel the way I am it at the moment in the 'check' function isn't actually returning other than an expression:

```
    validate = () => {
        const items = this.state.data;
        const check = e => {
            !e.error === undefined ? true : false;
        };
        const checkFields = items.some(check);

        if (!checkFields) {
            alert('form valid');
        }
    };
```

Is the 'check' function any good?

Comment: Form validation is a common thing so it's good to use a form validation library to keep things simple as possible. See [this](https://formvalidation.io) - [this](https://parsleyjs.org) or [this](http://pristine.js.org). Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `check` function does not return anything. Either:

- Remove the braces so that it no longer is a code block, but an expression whose value is returned, or
- Add a `return` before the expression.

Secondly:

The `!` operator has precedence over `===`, so `!e.error === undefined` is not doing what you think. You can use parentheses, like `!(e.error === undefined)`, but why not just `e.error !== undefined`?

And it really is not necessary to apply the ternary operator on that. It is already a boolean expression, so just use it without that `?  true : false`.

In short:

```
const check = e => e.error !== undefined;
```

Concerning the overall function `validate`: Using `alert` is quite primitive, and not the most user-friendly thing to do. You should consider applying CSS styling to the input that does not pass validation.

Comment: Ahhh it makes sense now! Thank you :)